# How to read Hbase table based on two family in a Table

Tags: hbase

I want to read a HBase table based on two family like name and age.
How do we do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, specifically why name and age would be families. If you meant column have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323700/is-there-any-way-to-limit-the-number-of-columns-in-hbase/5324242#5324242

Answer (score 0):

HBase has Tables, Column Families, and Column Qualifiers.  The general advice is to create as few column families as possible (<<10).

A row key specifies the particular data.  So, if you want to get a particular row you construct a Get:

```
Get g = new Get(rowkey);
```

Once you have a result your can pull out a given column qualifier by specifying the family/qualifier:

```
HTable t = new HTable(tablename);
Result row = t.get(g);
byte[] value = row.getValue(family, qualifier);
```

You can also iterate through all of the key/value pairs from the row (where the key contains the column family/column qualifier):

```
List<KeyValue> list = row.list();
for (KeyValue kv: list) {
...
}
```